# Elixir - Randomized numbers in Agent

Tags: random, elixir, agent

I'm trying to implement an Agent that behaves as a dice :

```
defmodule Dice do
  @on_load :seed_generator

  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> [] end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def roll(n, val) do
    Agent.cast(__MODULE__, fn(_) ->
      Stream.repeatedly(fn -> :random.uniform(val) end)
      |> Enum.take(n)
    end)
  end

  def seed_generator do
    :random.seed(:erlang.now)
    :ok
  end
end
```

However, the generated numbers are the same, every time I restart iex.
What am I doing wrong ? Is the seed not working because the  `:random.uniform` call is inside the Agent ? Or something related with the `Stream` maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `seed_generator` function is called in a different process than the one your `Agent` will be using. In fact that process doesn't even exist at the point this code is loaded. Try seeding the generator when starting the `Agent`:

```
defmodule Dice do
  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> :random.seed(:erlang.now) end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def roll(n, val) do
    Agent.get(__MODULE__, fn(_) ->
      Stream.repeatedly(fn -> :random.uniform(val) end)
      |> Enum.take(n)
    end)
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems to work, did this : `Agent.start_link(fn -> :random.seed(:erlang.now); [] end, name: __MODULE__)` to keep an empty list as the default state. Thank you.

Comment: You're ignoring the state anyway in the `roll` function, so I don't think it matters. Your actual state is the process dictionary where the state of the random generator is kept.

Comment: Instead of erlang.now(), the function os.timestamp() might be also good: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os.html#timestamp-0  Because erlang.now() might bring some problems.